# On() and off() - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to understand Jquery's On() and off() a little better. Not understanding why this is not working. I want to activate and inactivate id TurnON and TurnOff Js.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click.turnon","#TurnOn",function() {
        $(document).off('click.turnon');    
        alert("Turn Off is now turned off");
    });

    $(document).on("click.turnoff","#TurnOff",function() {
        $(document).on('click.turnon');
        alert("Turn Off is now turned back on");
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="TurnOn">Turn Off</div>
<div id="TurnOff">Turn On</div>
```

Comment: refer this link http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/ may be it is helpful for you

Comment: I check that out @chicko. I'm still having trouble understanding

Answer (score 7):

If you want an event handler to only fire once then take a look at `.one()`: http://api.jquery.com/one

As of jQuery 1.7 it does event delegation.

```
$(function(){

    $(document).one("click.turnon","#TurnOn",function() {  
        alert("Turn Off is now turned off");
    });

    $(document).one("click.turnoff","#TurnOff",function() {
        alert("Turn Off is now turned back on");
    });

});
```

Here is a demo using `.one()`: http://jsfiddle.net/9qxfT/1/

Also, your code was just about right but you have a couple typos here:

```
$(document).on("click.turnoff","#TurnOff",function() {
    $(document).on('click.turnon');
    alert("Turn Off is now turned back on");
});
```

`$(document).on('click.turnon');` should be: `$(document).off('click.turnoff');`

Here is a demo of these small changes: http://jsfiddle.net/9qxfT/

### Update

You can save the state with a variable:

```
$(function(){

    //declare a variable to save whether or not the `#TurnOn` element is 'on' (true) or 'off' (false)
    var isOn = true;
    
    $(document).on("click.turnon","#TurnOn",function() {

        //check to see if the flag is set to true, which means the `#TurnOn` element is 'on' already
        if (isOn) {
            alert("#TurnOn is already turned on");

        //otherwise set the `#TurnOn` element to 'on'
        } else {
            alert("#TurnOn is now turned back on");
            isOn = true;
        }
    });

    //set the `#TurnOn` element to `off` when the `#TurnOff` element is clicked
    $(document).on("click.turnoff","#TurnOff",function() {
        isOn = false;
        alert("#TurnOn is now turned off");
    });

});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9qxfT/4/

Comment: I want the event to fire more than once. Since I am using multiple events and want to avoid the event from looping

Comment: @Joe Each of your event handlers will fire only for the element to which it's attached, in this case the `click.turnoff` event handler only fires when the `#TurnOff` element is clicked. Here is a demo of just binding using `$(<root element>).on(<event>, <selector>, <event handler>)`: http://jsfiddle.net/9qxfT/2/

Comment: When i click Turn Off I would like the click.turnon to stop executing until I Click Turn On which will fire up the click.turnon again

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but take a look at the **update** to my answer.

Comment: No that is not it. When I click on <div id="TurnOn">Turn Off</div> I should get an alert "Turn Off is now turned off". So when I click "Turn Off" again I do not get the alert until I click <div id="TurnOff">Turn On</div>. This turns click.turnon back on.  From there I can click "Turn Off" and go through the whole cycle again. Hope this explains it. Thanks

Comment: This helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is right, but may I suggest better implementation?

Please read this page as well: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Here is what I suggest:

```
// first put a .click event with a separate "ID" to enable another div "ID".
$('#ButtonForTurnOn').click(function () {
//while body is .on(), the ID, when clicked applies whatever effects
$("body").on("click", "#TurnOn", onlight).find("#TurnOn").addClass("clickable").text("ON switch on");
});
// enable OFF switch
$('#ButtonForTurnOff').click(function () {
$("body").on("click", "#TurnOff", offlight).find("#TurnOff").addClass("clickable").text("OFF switch on");
});
```

Now, for you to have an effective `.off` function, YOU MUST have the

> "selector string match the one passed to .on() when the event handler
>   was attached."

For example:
If your `$("body").on()` is this,

```
$("body").on("click", "#TurnOff", function({
// stuff here
});
```

Your `$("body").off()` should be this,

```
$("body").off("click", "#TurnOff", function({
// stuff here
});
```

Try out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mlgmainstream/gk7Y4/39/)

Hope this helps explain things!
Just think of it as disabling something, until its turned back on.